# How, why do I have overfitting?

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameters, data-science

I am using the famous wine data set. 
I am trying to tune the hyperparameters using a for loop. But it seems that I have overfitting problem and I can't understand why.

```
from sklearn import datasets
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
wine = datasets.load_wine()
X = wine.data
y = wine.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=0)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, train_size=0.75, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)
X_val_std = sc.transform(X_val)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
C= [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01,0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
gamma=[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0]
kernel= ["linear","rbf"]
best_score = 0.0
best_C =0.0
best_gamma = 0.0
best_kernel = ""

for i in C:
    for j in gamma:
        for k in kernel:
            clf = SVC(C=i, gamma=j, kernel=k)
            clf.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
            y_predict_val = clf.predict(X_val_std)
            score = accuracy_score(y_val, y_predict_val)

            if score >= best_score:
                best_score = score
                best_gamma = j
                best_C =i
                best_kernel = k

print("Best C:",best_C, "Best Gamma:",best_gamma, "Best kernel:",best_kernel, "Best accuracy:",best_score)
```

This is the result I get when I run this.
[image]

```
clf_best = SVC(C=best_C, gamma=best_gamma, kernel=best_kernel)
clf_best.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
y_predict_test = clf_best.predict(X_test_std)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict_test))
```

I keep getting 1.0 as accuracy score for most of the parameter combinations(~60%). For the rest I get 0.44 and some other values. Can anyone spot where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you share all the code? Including the loading of the data and train/test splits?

Comment: @yatu I added .

Comment: I'm getting correct results. All seems ok to me

Comment: @yatu Yeah, but don't you think there is overfitting? When I predict the test set using the training model with the parameters I got using validation set, I got 100% accuracy. Is this possible to get 100% accuracy of predicting on the unknown data?

Comment: Yes this is a very small dataset, so basically the 3% error is probably just 1 sample. So yes, it is here

Comment: In any case, you would have overfitting if your test performance was too low, not the opposite; @yatu is right, this can certainly happen in such small datasets.